# How to create geometry symbols in HTML/CSS

Tags: html, geometry

I'm trying to suss out the best approach to creating geometry symbols for a website. Most of the normal things are easy (degrees, etc.) and have Unicode representations. However, I need to do rays and lines which have a directional arrow over the letters of the ray indicating origin and direction or a double-ended arrow indicating a line.

```
                       -->     <--> 
                       AB       AB
```

After having spent a few hours Googling, the best approach seems to be to just insert a graphic image, but that makes for a somewhat sloppy looking text flow.

Are there any other approaches to rendering that sort of combination character?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe using CSS `::after` with the symbol as your `content`, and putting it on top of your text might do what you're looking for. See [this pen](http://codepen.io/Ashugeo/pen/BojqRP).